# DNS problem trying to ping or send email using smtp-mail.outlook.com after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: dns, 17.10, smtp

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, I find I am unable to send emails using the confusingly named Outlook (i.e. what used to be Hotmail) SMTP server.

When I try to ping the hostname `smtp-mail.outlook.com` I get

```
ping: smtp-mail.outlook.com: Name or service not known
```

However when I try `nslookup smtp-mail.outlook.com` I get

```
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
smtp-mail.outlook.com   canonical name = smtp.live.com.
smtp.live.com   canonical name = smtp.glbdns2.microsoft.com.
smtp.glbdns2.microsoft.com  canonical name = smtp.office365.com.
smtp.office365.com  canonical name = smtp.outlook.office365.com.
smtp.outlook.office365.com  canonical name = outlook.office365.com.
outlook.office365.com   canonical name = lb.geo.office365.com.
lb.geo.office365.com    canonical name = outlook.office365.com.g.office365.com.
outlook.office365.com.g.office365.com   canonical name = outlook-emeawest2.office365.com.
Name:   outlook-emeawest2.office365.com
Address: 40.101.4.18
...
```

I have looked around on various other questions about DNS problems in Ubuntu and tried a couple of things but as far as I can see, everything appears to be in order. I can also ping other internet addresses, it seems to be just this one that is having trouble.

This was working fine before I upgraded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As a stopgap you can use `smtp.glbdns2.microsoft.com` or `outlook.office365.com` as smtp server.

Comment: @nathdwek Thanks. I discovered that I could use `outlook-emeacenter2.office365.com`, so I set that up but I'm a bit perplexed by this and wondering if I'll discover any other domain names that Ubuntu fails to resolve. Out of interest, do you know experience the same problem or know what's causing the problem even if you don't have a solution?

Comment: Just having the same problem :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, using systemd-resolved. LP bug reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1728560

A workaround is to look up an IP address for it from the command line using "host", then add it to your /etc/hosts file:

```
host smtp-mail.outlook.com
[choose IP_ADDRESS for the command below from one reported here]
sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo "IP_ADDRESS smtp-mail.outlook.com" >> /etc/hosts'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem to ping smtp-mail.outlook.com on my Notebook with Debian Stretch. I am able to ping the address from another computer with Debian Jessie. There I could find out that both smtp-mail.outlook.com and imap-mail.outlook.com point to outlook-emeacenter.office365.com, sometimes as well to outlook-emeacenter3.office365.com, outlook-emeacenter4.office365.com, etc. These seems to change all the time.
My current workaround solution is that I set up my mail program (evolution) with outlook-emeacenter5.office365.com as incoming mail server and outlook-emeacenter3.office365 as outgoing mailserver and everything seems to work fine. It is more a trial-and-error solution, but the best I could get running so far.

Comment: Thanks for this. Using alternative hostnames has been suggested already in the above comments (https://askubuntu.com/questions/969689/dns-problem-trying-to-ping-or-send-email-using-smtp-mail-outlook-com-after-upgra/1002323#comment1553568_969689)